# Viewing images in custom list

Tags: list, office-365, image, picture

I have a custom list with a column "Hyperlink or Picture" where I want to view pictures. I only figured out how to view pictures from the web (by inserting a hyperlink), but I want to view pictures from my local machine by uploading them to SharePoint.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Maybe by uploading them to a document library or picture library first, then linking them to my custom list?

Comment: That is exactly how could do it, upload the images to an image library and then use that URL in the hyperlink field

Comment: @RobertLindgren: Is it possible to restrain the image size (width and height)? Now, all images are unequal and my list looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Picture Library app to your site and upload the photos to that. That library type comes with a "Thumbnail" view by default.